# how to write custom map function in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have below line which split the words by space and I have map function where I want to pass my custom function to manipulate just for my learning and understanding better

```
val wordList = dataRdd.flatMap(x=>x.split(" ")).map(x=>(myMap(x)))

def myMap(word:String)
{
   if(wordMap.contains(word))
      {
        var value:Int = wordMap.get(word).get
            wordMap+=(word->(value+1))
      }else
      {
        wordMap+=(word->1)
      }
}
```

I have map where I am checking the words and if present I am incrementing by 1 and updating the map
what should be the return type of myMap function, how does the result stored in wordList?

can somebody explain please?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done like this (just read [Spark Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) about closures).

And the problem you try to solve is just a word count:

```
dataRdd.flatMap(_.split(" ").map((_, 1L))).reduceByKey(_ + _).collectAsMap
```